# Converting XML-RPC to JSON in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, xml-rpc

Can anyone recommend a lightweight JavaScript XML-RPC library?

After researching this a while ago, I couldn't find anything I was comfortable with, so I kinda ended up writing my own.
However, maybe that was stupid, as there must be something suitable out there!?

My own pseudo-library is mainly missing a way to turn an XML-RPC response into JSON - or rather, converting the respective responseXML to a JavaScript object (converting the [data types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML-RPC#Data_types) as needed).
This isn't hard to do, but why reinvent the wheel...

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: More here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143772/what-is-the-best-javascript-xml-rpc-client-library

Answer (score 2):

I know this two libraries, that you can basically use to convert your XML-RPC responses to JSON:

- [XML to JSON Converter](http://www.thomasfrank.se/xml_to_json.html)
- [xml2json.js](http://goessner.net/download/prj/jsonxml/)

Comment: Thanks. However, I was hoping for something that understands the XML-RPC specs so the data types are converted accordingly (instead of just converting the XML hierarchy as-is).
I'll update the original post accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to do what you (and I) want:

- http://kuriositaet.de/javascript/jsxmlrpc.html
- http://kuriositaet.de/javascript/xmlrpc.html
- http://sourceforge.net/projects/jsxmlrpc/

Answer (score 0):

Another small XML to JSON (and vice versa) JavaScript library is here -> http://code.google.com/p/x2js/

Answer (score -1):

I could use this too. Generic XML to Json is rather unconvenient for XML-RPC.