# What is the best Javascript XML-RPC client library?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml-rpc

What is the best Javascript XML-RPC client library in your opinion and why?

I'am making a JQuery app and I need to communicate with my xmlrpc server with it.

Found following libraries, but I have no idea what are their pros and cons:

http://www.zentus.com/js/xmlrpc.js.html

http://www.scottandrew.com/xml-rpc/

http://phpxmlrpc.sourceforge.net/jsxmlrpc/

http://www.vcdn.org/Public/XMLRPC/

http://mimic-xmlrpc.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 6):

There is a Google-hosted library here: http://code.google.com/p/json-xml-rpc/.
It supports both XML-RPC and JSON-RPC for JavaScript, and asynchronous as well as synchronous requests. I'm about to try out the XML-RPC for JavaScript myself with a JQuery UI and will update this based on my findings.

Comment: Seems that you cannot use XML-RPC protocol for cross-domain calls with this library. :(

Comment: else if(this.__protocol == 'XML-RPC') throw Error("Unable to use the XML-RPC protocol to access services on other domains.");

Comment: This seem to do the job very well. works on all major browsers. Great pair with Zope and Plone!

Answer (score 2):

There are two new libraries that I recently published for doing XML-RPC over JavaScript. One works with jQuery, one is plain JavaScript for modern browsers.

- [jQuery XML-RPC](http://plugins.jquery.com/xmlrpc/) ([docs](http://jquery-xml-rpc.readthedocs.org/en/latest/))
- [xmlrpc.js](https://bitbucket.org/tim_heap/xmlrpc.js)

Answer (score 1):

I have tried http://www.zentus.com/js/xmlrpc.js.html myself.  It has problems parsing the result in FireFox and Chrome, parsing the result in IE worked fine.

I have not tried the others, but 'mimic' looks great (if it works).

For my own problem, I've switched to JSON instead of XMLRPC.

Comment: Actually I've switched to JSON also. Mainly because I need JSONP abilities. 

But any how, it would be nice read more comments about these.

Answer (score 1):

I've had good luck with [jsolait](http://jsolait.net/) (specifically its 'xmlrpc' module), although the project appears to be dead now.

Answer (score 1):

For XML-RPC client calls in JavaScript to a remote server, I successfully used the RedStone XML-RPC library:

I was interfacing it with Python on the other side, I had to do a minor correction to the library though:

```
//  python xml-rpc does not has a handler name
var message = '<?xml version="1.0"?><methodCall><methodName>' + ((this.handlerName!="")?(this.handlerName + '.'):"") +  method + '</methodName>';
```

Answer (score 0):

The protocol is rather easy, are you sure you need a library at all? Maybe just send the XML the protocol requires?

Answer (score 0):

Adding a library to the list. I found this one quite easy to use, although I haven't tried all of the others that are mentioned.

- http://kuriositaet.de/javascript/jsxmlrpc.html
- http://kuriositaet.de/javascript/xmlrpc.html
- http://sourceforge.net/projects/jsxmlrpc/