# how to pass c array to javascript from C++

Tags: javascript, visual-c++, com, external, idispatch

i found some definition in "wtypes.h"

```
VT_PTR  = 26,
VT_SAFEARRAY    = 27,
VT_CARRAY   = 28,
VT_USERDEFINED  = 29,
VT_LPSTR    = 30,
VT_LPWSTR   = 31,


*  VT_PTR                 [T]        pointer type
*  VT_SAFEARRAY           [T]        (use VT_ARRAY in VARIANT)
*  VT_CARRAY              [T]        C style array
*  VT_USERDEFINED         [T]        user defined type
*  VT_LPSTR               [T][P]     null terminated string
*  VT_LPWSTR              [T][P]     wide null terminated string
```

In my opinion,this definition show that a Variant can as a c array,ptr or c point.
but can't get the type of arg when i use follow code to pass c array to javascript

```
STDMETHODIMP CFileSystemObject::Invoke( DISPID dispIdMember, REFIID riid, LCID lcid, WORD wFlags, DISPPARAMS *pDispParams, VARIANT *pVarResult, EXCEPINFO *pExcepInfo, UINT *puArgErr ){
    pVarResult->vt = VT_CARRAY|VT_I4;
    pVarResult->pintVal = new int[4];
}
```

how to pass c array to javascript from c++?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12005610/javascript-c-binding

Comment: @suspectus ,i think my question has some difference from your link.

Comment: what difference do you find?

Comment: my question's key point is how to use this definition to pass c array to javascript,i think this definition can help us to do it,but i can't find how to use it.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways you can achieve something close to your goal.

**A**) Have your method return a `SAFEARRAY` (see `SafeArrayCreate`, `SafeArrayAccessData` et al). You can then pack that into a variant of type `VT_ARRAY | VT_I4`. JavaScript cannot consume safearrays directly, but can with the help of `VBArray` object. On JavaScript side, the call would look something like this:

```
  var retArr = new VBArray(yourObject.yourMethod()).toArray()
```

Note that, if you want your method to be callable from VBScript in addition to JavaScript, VBScript only understands safearrays of variants (`VT_ARRAY | VT_VARIANT`), not of any other type. So you would need to create a safearray of variants, and have each of those variants wrap an int. JavaScript would work with such an arrangement, too.

**B**) Implement a separate COM collection object wrapping the array. That object would expose, say, `length` and `item()` properties for access to individual elements; and optionally `_NewEnum` property to play well with VBScript's `for each` syntax, if that's a concern. Your method would then create and return an instance of that object.

I think, though am not 100% sure, that a default property (one with `DISPID` of `DISPID_VALUE`) is accessible in JavaScript via `objectName[i]` syntax, in addition to the regular `objectName.item(i)` syntax. If that works, that would make the collection object look almost like a native JavaScript array.

**C**) Create, populate and return a native JavaScript Array object:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/88753/Creating-JavaScript-arrays-and-other-objects-from

I wouldn't personally recommend this, as it ties your component intimately to a particular host. I mention it for completeness.

Answer (score 1):

> `VT_CARRAY | VT_I4`

Has no chances to work out for obvious reason: the values 28 and 3 are not even OR'rable. The resulting value of 31 is nothing but `VT_LPWSTR`... Compare this to `VT_ARRAY` `0x2000` residing in separate bit position to not interfere with base type.

`VT_CARRAY` is a variant type on its own and I would not even expect it to be supported on JS side. Use safe arrays to have your data delivered to JS, this is a reliable alternate option.